# JavaFX scene scales differently in Scene builder and run time on Windows 10

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, javafx, scenebuilder

I using Scene Builder with Intelij IDEA to build a JavaFX application. The scene looks correct when I preview it in Scene Builder but when I then execute it in IntelliJ the scene is scaled up 1.5x. In Scene Builder the stage is 1280x800 but when I run the program it is 1920x1200 despite me setting the scene size 1280x800.

This seems like it might be due to Windows 10 scaling the application. If so, is there a way to stop my application from scaling?

Thank you!

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1280, 800));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with windows scaling. all you have to do is to remove these arguments inside your Scene i.e 1280 and 800, but don't remove root.

new code will be like -

```
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```